# Deprecated Java JList feature

Tags: java, jlist, deprecated

As a retirement project to learn and use Java I worked my way through a Deitel book that I bought in 2005.   I am now working on a cypher-breaking program that I thought up.   I have not yet progressed to using a tool such as Eclipse.   The Java compiler warns that "Java uses or overrides a deprecated API" and that "Java uses unscheduled or unsafe operations" concerning my use of a JList.   `<< private JList foundJList; >>  and << foundJList = new JList(); >>`

The program executes OK through my initial loading of data into the JList from a simple array    `<<  foundJList.setListData( sortedLetter ); >>` but the program throws an error later in the program on an identical `<<  foundJList.setListData( sortedLetter ); >>` statement after I have changed some values in the supporting array 'sortedLetter" .
<<< CORRECTION MAY 18 2014 >>>>   i had misunderstood the purpose of the setListData feature, assuming it loaded the JList from the array instead of its real purpose of binding the array to the JList.  I simply deleted the instruction containing the second setListData and then all went well.

Can you recommend a modern Java book that will cover a modern alternative to the deprecated JList feature?

Comment: What line of code did you get the "Java uses or overrides a deprecated API" message for?

Comment: The compile's warning messages did not provide any line numbers.   I expect to eliminate the compiler warnings after I have got myself a modern Java book and modified my coding.

Comment: I didn't ask what the line numbers were, although my Java compiler provides them. I asked what *lines of code*, and every compiler ever built clearly indicates those, one way or the other. By implication I am also asking whether that is the real error text. It doesn't seem likely.

Answer (score 1):

Try letting your JList know what kind of data it is intended to hold, something like:

```
JList<String> list = new JList<String>();
```

or

```
JList<String> list = new JList<>();
```

depending on your version of Java.

As far as current resources on Java, try the good ol' [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). I'll hazard a guess and say that your book may predate Java 1.5, which introduced the first of a number of big changes over the next couple of versions, including: SwingFX, Generics (which is what you ran into), JDBC, File I/O... just to name a few things off the top of my head. Your book should probably be repurposed as a doorstop at this point. I'd recommend using the tutorial until you hit a specialized area of interest that warrants another book -- the tutorial really is quite good.